# PHP - when to use error suppressing operator ( @( $obj->var ) ) and when to use null coalescing operator ( ?? )

Tags: php

I'm setting a variable on an object like this:

```
$new_var = @( $my_obj->var_value ) ?: '';
```

But this can be done with the null coalescing operator as well:

```
$new_var = $my_obj->var_value ?? '';
```

I'm thinking that the first option is the safest choice, since if `$my_obj` is null, then `$my_obj->var_value` would throw a runtime error, trying to access `var_value` on a null object. Or what?

But then my question is, when is it the better choice to ever use `??` over the single-line ternary shorthand `@( $foo->bar ) ?: ''`?

Comment: Note that in the latest php version you also have the "nullsafe operator": you can do `$my_obj?->var_value` . I personally never use the error suppressing operator.

Comment: The answer to the first question is simple: never. By suppressing the errors you hide a source of information about possible bugs in the code. Do not suppress the errors, fix them!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `@` operator is sometimes called the "shut up" operator: it silences **any and all warnings and errors** produced by the given statement. That makes it a rather crude tool: rather than saying "I am aware of a specific case in this code which I need to handle", it says "whatever goes wrong, just carry on and don't tell me about it".

In contrast, the `??` operator (and the newer `?->` operator) handle **one specific case**: the left-hand side might be null or unset, and you want to define the behaviour if it is.

The *effect* of the two expressions is probably quite similar in this case, but the *intent* with the `??` operator is much clearer.

Even better is to write code where you don't need such cases at all - for instance, a private property that is only written in the constructor is always in a known state; a public method returning that value can then return it without extra error suppression.

So instead of:

```
class MyClass {
    public $var_value;
}
$my_obj = new MyClass;

// I might have forgotten to set the property, so coalesce it
echo $my_obj->var_value ?? '';
```

You can write:

```
class MyClass {
    private string $var_value;
    public function __construct(string $var_value) {
        $this->var_value = $var_value;
    }
    public function get_var_value() {
        return $this->var_value;
    }
}
$my_obj = new MyClass('hello');

// No way for this to error, so no extra handling needed
echo $my_obj->get_var_value();
```